# Ajax data object as controller argument is null

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make an ajax call to my controller method, which accepts an object. I have tried the following right now:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditStudent(Student student) 
{
    //do something
}
```

Ajax call:

```
$('#submitEdit').click(function () {
    var object = 
        {
            Id: $('#StudentId').val(),
            StudentName: $('#StudentName').val(),
            Age: $('#Age').val(),
        };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Controller/EditStudent',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"Student" : JSON.stringify(object)},
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
        },
        error: function (data) {
            debugger;
        }
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, everything in my argument is null. I am sure, that the values I get from the respective Ids (`#StudentId`, `#StudentName`, `#Age`) are okay.

Besides the above, I have tried to add `[FromBody]` before the parameter in my method without any effect.

Comment: Try to remove contentType, dataType and JSON.stringify

Comment: Wow! why did that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in comment, removeing `contentType`, `dataType` and `JSON.stringify` fixes your problem.
That way, request is generated with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` and parameters are formed like `Student%5BId%5D=1&Student%5BStudentName%5D=2&Student%5BAge%5D=3`.

The problem I'm struggling by myself is why `[FromBody]` is not working in asp.net core 3 MVC controller. The way I do it where I need to get `JSON` is something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditStudent() 
{
    using (var bodyStreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.Body)) {
        var bodyText = await bodyStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        var student = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(bodyText);
        //do something
    }
}
```

If you will modify your action like this, I think it will get you a `student` object from ajax call you wrote in OP.

### Update

I figured out why `[FromBody]` was not working for me. I had few primitive types as arguments. As I switched them with single model, it worked perfectly.

In OP ajax must be like

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/EditStudent',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(object),
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
    },
    error: function (data) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

And C# code will be like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditStudent([FromBody]Student student) 
{
    //do something
}
```